# Error in apache configuration?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

The file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` that comes with the standard build is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    ....
```

Is there something wrong with line 5: `<Directory />`?  Wouldn't the /> close the <Directory element?

By the way, what is this block supposed to specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking 'proper XML'. An apache configuration file isn't. Strictly speaking, it should probably be enclosed in quotes. (e.g. `<Directory "/" >`)

That's specifying that - for the 'root' directory on your web server (probably `/var/www/html` or similar) that symlinks are allowed. (And '.htaccess' is disabled).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory